# Spring OAuth 2 - Database Schema as JPA Entities

Tags: spring, jpa, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I want to create the database for my JDBC TokenStore independent from the database type. So I want to use JPA Entities to automatically create tables and columns.

There are a lot of schemas (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)) for the database which is used by Spring OAuth2 to be found online.
But I can't find any JPA entities for these tables.

To be clear, I am searching for something like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "oauth_client_token")
public class OauthClientToken implements java.io.Serializable {
    [...]
}
```

Are there any of them flying around?
It would not be much work to create them, but I don't want to make any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would've made sense if these JPA entities were available. 
Probably the reason why they didn't add JPA entities is because not all of the tables have primary keys, like:

```
create table oauth_refresh_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token LONGVARBINARY,
  authentication LONGVARBINARY
);
```

JPA requires that every entity have an primary key. It is possible to create your own entity and add an incremental ID as primary key, however I am not sure if this will have negative impact or not.